# Overwrite parmeter of the CreateTextFile Methode of an FileSystemObject (VBA)

Tags: vba, text-files

The following code gives me an error if the file already exists:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim TextFile As Object
Dim SomeFilePath As String
SomeFilePath = "C:\test.txt"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TextFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(SomeFilePath, False)
```

is this expected behavior or am I missing s.th.? Seem to me that [CreateTextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method) shouldn't create an error here but just skip the creation of a new file if the value `false` has been used. If I have to check for existing files in order to avoid the error beforehand, having the parameter seems to be superfluous. Any explanation here?

Comment: [Use `OpenTextFile` to append to an existing file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method), or `CreateTextFile( path, True )` to overwrite/replace the original.

Comment: "_if the value false has been used._"  - it's the other way around: use `True` to allow the file to be overwritten, use `False` to have it fail if the file exists. [It's all in the documentation I linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method).

Answer (score 1):

> The following code gives me an error if the file already exists:
>
> ```
> Set TextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(SomeFilePath, False)
> ```
>
> is this expected behavior or am I missing s.th.?

The second parameter to the `CreateTextFile()` method is the optional `BOOL overwrite` parameter, documented as-follows:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method
>
> `overwrite` - Optional - **Boolean** value that indicates if an existing file can be overwritten.
>
> - The value is `True` if the file can be overwritten.
> - `False` if it can't be overwritten.
> - If omitted, existing files can be overwritten.

And observe that your VBA Code has `objFSO.CreateTextFile(SomeFilePath, False)`, *ergo* the `overwrite` parameter argument is `False`.

...which means that if `SomeFilePath` represents a file that already exists, then `CreateTextFile` will fail, thus avoiding overwriting the file.

To gracefuly handle this error, use VBA's `On Error Goto...` statement, with a `label:` destination which contains error-handling code.

Alternatively, if you want the file to be retained, and have new text appended to it, then use [`objFSO.OpenTextFile(filename, ForAppending, True)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method) (you **must** specify `ForAppending`, otherwise it will fail just like `CreateTextFile` - while the `True` value in this case is for the `create` parameter, so that if `filenam` does not exist, it will behave the same as `CreateTextFile`.